# How to set _NET_WM_STATE in python xlib

Tags: python, xlib

I want to write my own dock for my window manager. I saw polybar has `_NET_WM_STATE` set to `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` and `_NET_WM_STATE_STICKY`. I want to do the same in `python-xlib` but there's no documentation regarding this problem or at least I can't find it. Could anyone show me how it's done? Also, if there's a better way to write a bar then I'd appreciate if you show it to me.